# Rails Devise/Invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I have a Rails app with devise and **[devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#configuring-controllers)** (links to official docs on overriding controllers), I have made a devise_invitable `invitations_controller.rb` to display a list of currently invited users within devise/invitations/new.html.erb. Both devise and devise_invitable views are in `app/views/devise` and `app/views/devise/invitations` respectively and my devise/devise_invitable controllers are in `app/controllers/users/`. Rails throws an `undefined method 'each' for NilClass` in the `invitations/new` view in my loop:

```
# app/views/devise/invitations/new.html.erb
<% @invited_users.each do |invited| %>
  omitting code...
<% end %>

# app/controllers/users/invitations_controller.rb
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def new
    super
    # This is not empty, returns multiple records in console
    @invited_users = User.where.not(invitation_sent_at: nil)
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
...
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations', 
                                  invitations: 'users/invitations' }   
...
end
```

The weird thing is that when I change the app/views/devise folder name to app/views/users, the error is gone and it displays current invited users but this creates a larger problem which is that the app now uses both devises/devise_invitable's default views.

Comment: Can you share the backtrace and the invitations/new view?

Comment: Turns out that the culprit was my super statement, the render was being called so it never actually got to the @invited_users, I just moved it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the culprit was my super statement, the render was being called so it never actually got to the @invited_users, I just moved it below